# How can I click the "ABOUT" button on a YouTube channel page?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

I am trying to click the "ABOUT" button on a YouTube channel page.
[image]

However, Chrome didn't show the  "ABOUT" information after I ran the following code.

```
! pip install selenium
from selenium import webdriver

! pip install beautifulsoup4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import time
import requests
import random
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:\chromedrive\chromedriver.exe')
keyword=['"K_Pop TV"']

for kk in keyword:
    driver.get("http://youtube.com")
    #enter keyword
    driver.find_element_by_name("""search_query""").send_keys(kk)
    #search
    driver.find_element_by_id("search-icon-legacy").click()
    time.sleep(2)
    #click the first channel
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div#avatar.style-scope.ytd-channel-renderer').click()
    time.sleep(2)
    #click "ABOUT"
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('tp-yt-paper-tab.style-scope.ytd-c4-tabbed-header-renderer').click()
```

Chrome paused on the "HOME" of the page of YouTube channel. It didn't keep going to show the "ABOUT". Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using locator that is not unique.
Try this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//div[@class="tab-content style-scope tp-yt-paper-tab"])[last()]').click()
```

It is unique and not based on text that also can change

Comment: any specific reason to use class here ? cause I personally think that it may change while About` text will never change

Comment: @cruisepandey class names are much stable while text may vary for user locale language. For example I see some other language / text there :)

Comment: Well I thought OP would run on en-US

Answer (score 0):

try with xpath below :

```
//div[contains(text(),'About')]
```

and click it like it below  :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(),'About')]").click()
```